How to perform Full-Text search with special characters (-, _, :, .) using the query builder?
I'm working on a search functionality in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) and need to perform a full-text search using Query Builder. My search input can include special characters like -, _, :, and .. However, it seems that these characters are not being considered in the search, and the results are not accurate.
For example:
Searching for example-doc_1 doesn't return a result, even though the content exists in the repository.
I'm using the following query parameters:
{
  "type": "dam:Asset",
  "fulltext": "example-doc_1",
  "path": "/content/my-site"
} 


Full Text Search by design will break and stem all words it finds, breaking up on things like punctuation. It's not doing LIKE, it's doing a semantic index of the text. It sounds like you want LIKE (and possibly a trigram index depending on your DBMS).
